# Anti Aliased Fonts with NoMachine NX

Tags: ubuntu, x11, remote-desktop, nx

I am running nx server on a headless ubuntu server. Its desktop is to Unix -> Custom -> Emacs which gives me an Emacs window on the local machine. The only thing that does not work as expected is the anti aliased fonts. I do have anti aliased fonts on my local X but nx seems to not honor my remote Xresources file.

Comment: Is the system you're displaying to also an Ubuntu box?

Comment: @sim yes ubuntu to ubuntu

Comment: Does this thread sound like your issue: [Thread: Can't see any text with NX on 12.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12345996#post12345996). The thread has a workaround for downgrading libcairo.

Answer (score 0):

Came across these 2 threads:

- [NX Issues with 12.10](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/272414-nx-issues-with-12-10)
- [Thread: Can't see any text with NX on 12.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12345996#post12345996)

There's a workaround described in the 2nd link that details downgrading libcairo.

#### workaround steps

Terminate your NX sessions

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/c/cairo/libcairo2_1.10.2-6.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
$ mkdir libcairo
$ dpkg -x libcairo2_1.10.2-6.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb libcairo/
$ sudo mkdir /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo_orig
$ sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-1. gnu/libcairo_orig/
$ sudo cp ~/Downloads/libcairo/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Re-connect to your machine via NX.